# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream) NGINX, Gunicorn when running Flask App

Tags: nginx, flask, nginx-reverse-proxy, amazon-linux

I'm trying to host a flask application on a Public EC2 instance on `Amazon-Linux-2` using `aws-cdk`.

I've configured nginx such for a custom health check endpoint /healthcheck
i have created a python env and installed gunicorn there and ran `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app` in my python env and was able to hit the endpoint ('/' for POST method)using POSTMAN. But the problem arises when i try to create a myproject.service file. the `myproject.sock` file is created , it has all the necessary permission `chmod 755 /home/ec2-user/myproject` , the `systemctl status myproject` also says running but now I can't hit the POST request using POSTMAN.

My `reverse.proxy` file is as follows-

configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

        location /healthcheck {
                limit_except GET {
                        deny all;
                }
                access_log off;
                return 200 "healthy\n";
        }

        location / {
                    error_page 405 =200 $uri;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  }
}
```

Where '/' is used to serve post requests from my flaskapp.py file

This is how myproject.service file looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The sock file is also created and running successfully but unable to hit POST

this is how my flaskapp.py looks

```
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handler():
    return f''' Hello {request.get_json()['name']}'''
```

and this is how my `wsgi.py` looks

```
from myproject import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

Not able to understand what is wrong that when i run `gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app` , i'm able to hit POST requests but when in exit gunicorn and try to create a `myproject.service` , i can't seem to hit POST requests. The /healthcheck works fine!

Please provide insight

Comment: I think your NGINX config (`proxy_pass`) should point to the `myproject.sock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NGINX config is pointing to a server listening on localhost port 5000, but your service is listening on the unix socket `myproject.sock`. As such, NGINX can't find the server when you run the service.

Try to set your NGINX config to something like:

```
server {
   ...
   location / {
      ...
      proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/myproject.sock;
   }
}
```

This should work when `gunicorn` is listening on a unix socket, such as in your service.

You need to make sure that NGINX can read and write to the unix socket. Run `stat /path/to/myproject.sock` and make sure that NGINX's user (most likely, `nginx`) has enough permissions.

Consider taking the docker way here: create a group only for the `myproject.sock` and the clients supposed to connect to it (i.e: `nginx` user and so on)

Comment: Changed it to proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ec2-user/myproject/myproject.sock;

Still no luck!

Comment: @MaheshM you should declare the URI scheme as well: `http://unix:/...`

Comment: The URI has been declared , but Stackoverflow formatted it in my comment making http disappear.

Comment: Also the logs in 

sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log , 


sudo less /var/log/nginx/access.log ,


sudo journalctl -u nginx ,


sudo journalctl -u myproject ,


look fine (have no conflicts)!

Comment: I can use POST from postman and i'm able to view the expected output when running the command 
`gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 wsgi:app` in virtualenv.

The server responds as intended but not for myproject.service

Comment: @MaheshM does your socket's permissions allow the service's user to read/write from it?

Comment: @MaheshM else, try `curl`ing to your socket to see if the server is properly working. See [this](https://superuser.com/a/925610) to curl to unix sockets.

Comment: Thank you for the response. cURL is not working , gives 405 method not allowed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248693/discussion-between-edg956-and-mahesh-m).